Clarification on interpretation of claimed factoring complexity (GNFS)
I hope you can help me with some confusion I have regarding a complexity function I encountered. The function in question is (Desmos syntax):
$$ y = e^{(\ln(x)^{\frac{1}{3}}) \cdot (\ln(\ln(x))^{\frac{2}{3}})} $$
From here: enter link description here
I noticed on Desmos that this curve is very flat at the point that it almost overlaps with the x-axis and for instance, it outputs a value of about 96.3 at (x = 10^6), and, unless I got wrong the expression on Desmos, I'm puzzled on how to understand what this function signifies in terms of algorithmic efficiency. Normally I interpret these expressions as intuitively proportional to the max number of steps as a function of the input (in this case the input size is the number of digits of a modulus or product). But here we have only 96 for n = 1 million, while it is well known that even the largest factorizations ever done are less than 800 digits with almost 1000 core-years of computing power (?) (So I guess that any meaningful curve describing real asymptotic behaviour should look about "vertical" (or "shoot up") much before reaching 2048 bits (?))
While I'm somewhat accustomed to standard complexity classes like (O(n)) and (O(n^2)) (for instance multiplying 2 numbers can be done in n^2 or a little less (n^1.56), and so on), this particular expression does not seem to fit in my usual interpretation.
Could anyone explain how it works ?
What does this output generally represent in the context of algorithm analysis?
How should I interpret this number in relation to computational efficiency or performance?
Are there practical examples or applications where such a function would apply?
I appreciate any insights you can provide. Thank you!
